# When I created a stage it doesn't allow me to draw sprites in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite, batch-processing

I was making a game in libgdx where a turtle has to collect StarFish but I was using actors and so I had to use a stage. After creating a stage I'm unable to draw sprites on the screen and also it crashes the game

EDIT:  I forgot to put batch.end() in the end, but still it doesn't draw the sprites

Here's my code

```
@Override
public void render()
{
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) 
        {
            Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(i), Gdx.input.getY(i), 0);
            camera.unproject(touchPos);
            Rectangle touch = new Rectangle(touchPos.x-16, touchPos.y-16, 32, 32);

            if (touch.overlaps(leftButton))
            {
                moveX-=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()*80;
                System.out.println("left touched");
            }
            if (touch.overlaps(rightButton))
            {
                moveX+=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()*80;
                System.out.println("right touched");
            }
            if (touch.overlaps(jumpButton))
            {
                moveY+=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()*80;
                System.out.println("up touched");
            }
        }
    }
    
    // check user input
    mainStage.act(1/60f);
    // check win condition: turtle must be overlapping starfish
    if (turtle.overlaps(starfish))
    {
        starfish.remove();
        winMessage.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    // clear screen
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // draw graphics
    mainStage.draw();
    
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();

    leftSpriteButton.draw(batch);
    rightSpriteButton.draw(batch);
    jumpSpriteButton.draw(batch);
    
    
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are using a different camera projection or Viewport type than the stage, so they aren't aligning correctly.

Comment: Yes maybe, so how I fix it I'm a newbie, I think I didn't use any viewports or camera in stage

Comment: You should have some Viewport that manages the camera for your sprite buttons. So instead of instantiating that camera directly, you instantiate a Viewport and grab a reference to that Viewport's camera. On the line right after `mainStage.draw()`, call `viewport.apply()` to reset any GL-viewport parameters that the stage has set and use your UI viewport's parameters instead.

Comment: Think of your game and your UI as two separate scenes drawn with different viewports/cameras. They don't have to be the same scale or anything. `stage.draw()` internally calls `viewport.apply()` and `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)` on its own internal Viewport and Camera. You must repeat these steps when drawing your UI layer, using your UI layer's Viewport and Camera. Since you are not using a Stage for your UI, you must do it manually.

Comment: And if you're not very far along, a tip. Most seasoned libGDX users I think would say that Stage/scene2d should mostly be used only for UI. Building the game layer without it, you end up having to build a little bit more low level stuff to move your game elements around and animate them, but you are freed from the rules of the scene graph so you can build something that works best for the genre of your game. This is only a sort of rule of thumb and not universally true, but you kind of have it flipped since you're using Scene2d for your game and not for your UI.